# PHP pagination for loop (trying to limit the pagination tabs)

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to make a pagination for my project,

Im am trying to learn some new skills and decided to start an old project i started a while ago and thought everything was going well and thought i had succeeded...

With the example data I have in my database everything seemed perfect, however when I imported more example data I noticed the pagination tabs were getting very long

currently i have them working as `1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10`

but after i imported more data the list went onto 50+

the PHP code i am using is

```
<?php  
for ($x = 1; $x <= $page_neeed; $x++) {
if ($page==$x){$class="active";}else{$class="";};
echo "<li class='page-item $class'><a class='page-link' href='example.php?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
}
?>
```

I have had a look at other sites and decided to have something like `1|2|3|...|50|51|52`

For the life of me, I can't get my head around how to approach this.

if you could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic as I don't know what to even search to try to solve this.

Comment: the simplest approach: say your threshold is 10 pages. Then if you know you got more, then you print first 5, then `...` (or anything to tell users there's more but not shown) and the last 5 pages. So for 11, you'd get `1|2|3|4|5 ... 7|8|9|10|11`

Comment: Pagination links can be straightforward, like yours with a single `for` loop, or complicated, where, for example, you want to display the 1st page, last page, current page, and up-to X pages on either side, etc. To give you an idea, here's how Laravel does it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/9.x/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views and https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/9.x/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination; those Classes and Files are used to construct the various links, so yeah...

Comment: Sidenote, you likely won't get an actual answer here, as asking for off-site resources is considered off topic for Stackoverflow. This isn't a bad question at all, but simply not one that we'll be able to answer, sorry. (Although you did edit your question and removed the explicit ask, so maybe; who knows)

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for the reference and the advice regarding the question. ill look into it more. i honestly thought i was over thinking things lol

Comment: No problem! I tried to write my own paginator once, but then opted to do what you did; a simple `for()` loop to show all the pages, and combined with a large enough "per page" value, it worked just fine (small data and what not). If you do figure it out, feel free to post a self-answer below; you might end up helping someone else. Cheers, and good luck!

Comment: @TimLewis I soon figured out that this was far more complex than I first thought. I have posted my code as an answer and like to thank you for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around with the links that Tim Lewis gave me in the comments on the OP I soon realised it was more complex than I first thought.

But....

I have managed to get a better pagination than I first had, almost the way I need.

I thought I would post the code here in case someone else could use it.

```
<?php

$max = $pages_needed-4;
//if we need more than 6 pages
if ($pages_needed > 6) {    

//seeing if the current page is between 5 and the last page -4
if (($page >= 5 && $page < $max)) {
$lower_page = $page - 2;
$next_page = $page + 1;
    for ($x = $lower_page; $x <= $next_page; $x++) {
if ($page == $x) {
    $class = "active";
} else {
    $class = "";
}
echo "<li class='page-item $class'><a class='page-link' href='$share_url/category/$category_slug?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
}
echo "<li class='page-item'><span class='page-link'>...</span></li>";
echo "<li class='page-item $class'><a class='page-link' href='$share_url/category/$category_slug?page=$pages_needed'>$pages_needed</a></li>";
};


//seeing if the current page is near the end
if (($page >= $max && $page < $pages_needed+1)) {
$lower_page = $page - 2;
$next_page = $page + 1;

echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$share_url/category/$category_slug?page=1'>1</a></li>";
echo "<li class='page-item'><span class='page-link'>...</span></li>";
    for ($x = $lower_page; $x <= $pages_needed; $x++) {
if ($page == $x) {
    $class = "active";
} else {
    $class = "";
}
echo "<li class='page-item $class'><a class='page-link' href='$share_url/category/$category_slug?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
}


};


//seeing if the current page is near the start
if (($page >= 1 && $page < 5)) {
$lower_page = $page - 2;
$next_page = $page + 1;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
if ($page==$x){$class="active";}else{$class="";};
echo "<li class='page-item $class'><a class='page-link' href='$share_url/category/$category_slug?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
}
echo "<li class='page-item'><span class='page-link'>...</span></li>";
echo "<li class='page-item $class'><a class='page-link' href='$share_url/category/$category_slug?page=$pages_needed'>$pages_needed</a></li>";
};
}
//if we need more less 6 pages

else{


for ($x = 1; $x <= $pages_needed; $x++) {
if ($page==$x){$class="active";}else{$class="";};
echo "<li class='page-item $class'><a class='page-link' href='$share_url/category/$category_slug?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
}
}   
?>
```

This alows me to have `1|2|3|4|5|6`

When on page 5 it goes `3|4|[5]|6|...|30|`

On the last 6 pages it gives you `1|...|26|27|28|29|30`

I'm pretty sure someone could simplify this but I'm still learning and hope this helps someone else.